# .map is not returning the values(not a function)

Tags: json, reactjs, object, next.js, map-function

I am trying to return the list of similar blogs which i have stored in the database to a component in nextjs.

But i am getting an Error `related.map is not a function`

I tried debugging using { JSON.stringify(related) }
which is giving me the response of JSON object.

```
{"related":{"_id":"5eab0a0b2741da18f0d3624e","title":"lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum  ....","slug":"lorem-blog-3-one",
"postedBy":{"_id":"5e9d3833a73b2c0cec9f5e1c","name":"user1","profile":"http://localhost:3000/profile/RxAq9u5Ck"},"updatedAt":"2020-04-30T17:25:31.977Z"}}
```

The function i'm using

```
 const showRelatedBlogs = () => {
        return related.map((blog, i) => (
            <div className="col-md-4" key={i}>
                <article>
                    <RelatedCard blog={blog} />
                </article>
            </div> 

        ));
    };
```

Comment: if my answer helped you can you mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response you are getting from your server shows that you are not getting a list of blogs but instead 1 blog. You have 2 options

1. Make your server return an array of blogs. So your JSON response would be:

```
{
    "related": [
        {
            "_id": "5eab0a0b2741da18f0d3624e",
            "title": "lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum  ....",
            "slug": "lorem-blog-3-one",
            "postedBy": {
                "_id": "5e9d3833a73b2c0cec9f5e1c",
                "name": "user1",
                "profile": "http://localhost:3000/profile/RxAq9u5Ck"
            },
            "updatedAt": "2020-04-30T17:25:31.977Z"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5eab0a0b2741da18f0d3624e",
            "title": "lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum  ....",
            "slug": "lorem-blog-3-one",
            "postedBy": {
                "_id": "5e9d3833a73b2c0cec9f5e1c",
                "name": "user1",
                "profile": "http://localhost:3000/profile/RxAq9u5Ck"
            },
            "updatedAt": "2020-04-30T17:25:31.977Z"
        },
        //...
    ]
}
```

Then in your component you can then use the `.map` function like you were doing.

2. You only show one blog info. So rather than mapping you should just show 1. Your component will look like this:

```js
// Lets say `related` is a prop
const showRelatedBlog = ({ related }) => {
    return (
        <div className="col-md-4">
            <article>
                <RelatedCard blog={related} />
            </article>
        </div> 

    );
};
```

Comment: Thank you it worked , i changed the api  server to return an array of blogs

Comment: Great. glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call an array's method `.map` on a plain object, `related` should be an array.